# Using a regex search with sed to sort entries in a file

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a text file of the following form:

```
dir1/sub-dir1/.../filename1 author date
dir1/sub-dir1/.../filename2 author date
.
.
.
dir2/sub-di2/.../filename1 author date
dir2/sub-dir2/.../filename2 author date
```

Additional details:

- Every filename listed exists precisely 1 time or 2 times. That is, `filename_n` exists precisely 1 time or 2 times. If it exists 1 time, it is in only 1 version of our software, v1 or v2, depending on the path. If it exists 2 times, the file is in both v1 and v2.
- The path determines if the file is in v1 or if it is in v2.
- The text file has is tab delimitted.
- The number of subdirectories varies from file to file (hence the `...` in the code block.)
- (The authors and dates were not taken from `ls`. They were generated separately, by interrogating the git commits that last recorded changes to these files.)

I am trying to use sed with a regex to transform the file so that it looks like this:

```
dir1/sub-dir1/.../filename1 author date dir2/sub-di2/.../filename1 author date
dir1/sub-dir1/.../filename2 author date dir2/sub-dir2/.../filename2 author date
.
.
.
```

If `filename-n` does not have a match, then it should appear only once, not twice.

I'm looking for a way to use sed and regex to perform the transformation. It can either be written to the same file (with `-i`), or it can be written to a separate file.

Comment: Are filenames unique even without paths, i.e. is there no name that exists in different directories?

Comment: "Every file listed exists either 1 time or 2 times." :-)

Comment: OK, so things like `v1/config.yml` and `v1/subproject/dir/config.yml` don't happen.

Comment: Exactly. What will happen frequently, though, is `v1/../config.yml` and `v2/../config.yml`.

Comment: Is there is reason for backslashes instead of slashes to separate directories in paths?

Comment: See my comment on your answer. (I edited the problem description.)

Comment: Those elipses (`...`s) in your sample input/output make it harder to understand and test with, you should get rid of them and just leave us something concrete we can copy/paste to test with. Also you say `If filename-n does not have a match, then it should appear only once, not twice.` - if such a case can occur in your real data then include such a case in your example data so it gets tested.

Answer (score 0):

One could do this entirely with `sed`, but this would result in a complex script which is hard to comprehend, so I would suggest to sort the file by the filenames first and then use `sed` to join lines if a filename is found twice.

The filenames are in the third subdirectory, to we tell `sort` to use the fourth field (`-k 4`) with the `\` (why on earth!!) as field separator:

```
sort -t'\' -k 4 /tmp/p|sed 'N;/\(\\[^\]*        \).*\1/s/\n/    /;P;D'
```

The `sed` command uses the typical `N;P;D` cycle to always process two lines at once and check whether the filename (between `\` and TAB) gets repeated.

Please note that that there are two literal tabs in the `sed` scripts. With GNU `sed`, you could write `\t` instead:

```
sort -t'\' -k 4 /tmp/p|sed 'N;/\(\\[^\]*\t\).*\1/s/\n/\t/;P;D'
```

Also note that paths including TAB characters or backslashes can break the script.

Comment: @Phillipos, I'm the OP. I made one correction, and one clarification in the problem definition.
Correction: You're right; the file delimiters are `/`, not `/`. (I work both on a Windows machine and a Mac, so I get these mixed up.)
Clarification: The number of `/` characters will vary from file to file, so `-k 4` will not always work.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box no matter which characters your paths contain (other than newlines):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{
    file = $0
    sub(".*/","",file)
    paths[file] = (file in paths ? paths[file] OFS : "") $0
}
END {
    for ( file in paths ) {
        print paths[file]
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
dir1/sub-dir1/.../filename2 author date dir2/sub-dir2/.../filename2 author date
.       .       .
dir1/sub-dir1/.../filename1 author date dir2/sub-di2/.../filename1 author date
```

If the output order actually matters it's a trivial tweak - just tell us what the output order should be (e.g. first read, alphabetical by file name, alphabetical by directory, something else).